# Is there a way to set the target for a task dynamically with the App Engine Java runtime?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, task-queue

When enqueuing a background task with the App Engine Python runtime, you can [specify a target for the queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) which will send the task to be run on a specific service, version, or instance:

```
task = taskqueue.add(
    url='/update_counter',
    target='worker',
    params={'amount': amount})
```

Is there a way to do this in Java? The documentation [mentions the `target` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) but doesn't show an example of how to use it. The [`Queue.add`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue.html#add-com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions-) method has no option for `target`. The [`TaskOptions`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#url-java.lang.String-) class doesn't have anything that looks like `target`, either.

[This question documents how to use the `target`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481769/how-to-use-modules-in-google-app-engine-and-add-a-target-to-them-using-task-queu), but the answer is to configure it in `queue.xml`. I'd like to pick the target at runtime, like Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** - There might be a way to do this based off earlier version of the documentation, but this is not described in the latest version of the documentation.

## Approach based on the latest documentation

As per the [latest documentation regarding Push queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-push-queues) (and like you already mentioned), you can configure the target module, version in the `queue.xml` per queue. If specified, the request for the task is sent to the specified target. As you already described, this is a static configuration and does not really answer your question (describing just for the sake of completeness).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <queue-entries>
    <queue>
      <name>queue-blue</name>
      <target>v2.task-module</target>
    </queue>
    <queue>
      <name>queue-red</name>
      <rate>1/s</rate>
    </queue>
  </queue-entries>
```

In the [documentation for creating tasks and specifying worker service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service), it describes about the target chosen for the task but does not clearly describe how to specify it.

> When a task is popped off its queue, the Task Queue service sends it
>   on to a worker service. Every task has a target and a url, which
>   determine what service and handler will ultimately perform the task.
>
> `target`
>
> The target specifies the service that will receive the HTTP request to
>   perform the task. It is a string that specifies a
>   service/version/instance in any one of the canonical forms. The most
>   often-used ones are:
>
> ```
> service
> version.service
> instance.version.service
> ```
>
> The target string is prepended to the domain name of your app. There
>   are three ways to set the target for a task:
>
> - Explicity declare the target when you construct the task.
> - Include a target directive when you define a queue in the queue.xml, as in the definition of queue-blue above. All tasks added to a queue
>     with a target will use that target, even if a different target was
>     assigned to the task at construction time.
> - If no target is specified according to either of the previous two methods, then the task's target is the version of the service that
>     enqueues it. Note that if you enqueue a task from the default service
>     and version in this manner, and the default version changes before the
>     task executes, it will run in the new default version.
>
> `url`
>
> The `url` selects one of the handlers in the target service, which will
>   perform the task.
>
> The `url` should match one of the handler URL patterns in the target
>   service. The url can include query parameters if the tasks's method is
>   `GET` or `PULL`. If no url is specified the default URL
>   `/_ah/queue/[QUEUE_NAME]` is used, where `[QUEUE_NAME]` is the name of the
>   task's queue.

Based off the above documentation, if you look at [`TaskOptions.Builder`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.Builder), there is no method to specify the target for the task. This could either indicate a missing documentation on how the target should be specified or just that there is no way any more to specify the target dynamically when adding the task to the queue. Look at the approach described below based on the earlier documentation.

## Approach based on earlier documentation

**DISCLAIMER:** What I mention here looks to be based on outdated information (I've cited the sources below) and hence might not work as expected and/or break in the future.

You can use the `Host` header to specify the module, version and instance information which will get the request.

To specify module and version, you can do:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("QUEUE_NAME");
    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder
            .withUrl("/url/path")
            .param("key", "PARAM")
            .header("Host",
                    ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getVersionHostname("MODULE_NAME", "VERSION")));
```

To specify instance you can do:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("QUEUE_NAME");
    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder
            .withUrl("/url/path")
            .param("key", "PARAM")
            .header("Host",
                    ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getInstanceHostname("MODULE_NAME", "VERSION", "INSTANCE_NAME"));
```

I could not find this info in the current version of the App Engine documentation, but using the Wayback machine I found this info from an [earlier version of the doc from Jan 1 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907020226/https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) which describes the Push task execution. It has been discussed in a different context in this [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/issues/18) as well.

> ## Push task execution
>
> App Engine executes push tasks by sending HTTP POST requests to your
>   app. Specifying a programmatic asynchronous callback as an HTTP
>   request is sometimes called a web hook. The web hook model enables
>   efficient parallel processing.
>
> The task's URL determines the handler for the task and the module that
>   runs the handler.
>
> The handler is determined by the path part of the URL (the
>   forward-slash separated string following the hostname), which is
>   specified by the url parameter in the TaskOptions that you include in
>   your call to the Queue.add() method. The url must be relative and
>   local to your application's root directory.
>
> The module and version in
>   which the handler runs is determined by:
>
> - The "Host" header parameter
>     in the TaskOptions that you include in your call to the Queue.add()
>     method.
> - The target directive in the queue.xml or queue.yaml file.
>
> If you do not specify any of these parameters, the task
>   will run in the same module/version in which it was enqueued, subject
>   to these rules:
>
> - If the default version of the app enqueues a task, the task will run
>     on the default version. Note that if the app enqueues a task and the
>     default version is changed before the task actually runs, the task
>     will be executed in the new default version.
> - If a non-default version
>     enqueues a task, the task will always run on that same version.
>
> Note:
>   If you are using modules along with a dispatch file, a task's URL may
>   be intercepted and re-routed to another module.
>
> The namespace in which
>   a push task runs is determined when the task is added to the queue. By
>   default, a task will run in the current namespace of the process that
>   created the task. You can override this behavior by explicitly setting
>   the namespace before adding a task to a queue, as described on the
>   multitenancy page.

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I was looking for. I tried it and confirmed it still works. I wonder why it was removed from the documentation...

Also, through experimentation, I've discovered that if the specified version doesn't exist, the task will run on the version serving traffic. I believe this is because the dispatcher will send unknown versions to the serving version.

This is nice because if you haven't deployed the backend version yet, the task will still run.